# jQuery Div will not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a div to hide in jQuery when a user is not logged in. I have a condition that should accomplish this, but I am getting no result from it. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    initHideMenuItem();
});

function initHideMenuItem() {
  var loggedin = '{module_isloggedin}';
  if  (loggedin == 1){
    jQuery("div.personal-tag").show();
  }
  else {
    jQuery("div.personal-tag").hide();
  }
}
```

In case you would like to know "{module_isloggedin}" is  a tag that has a value of either 0 or 1.

html:

```
<div class="personal-tag" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Welcome, {module_firstname}: 
  <span class="blue">{module_customerfield,170943,513231}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include the HTML code? just to check the class and id of the div...

Comment: I have solved the issue. After quite a bit of work and re-organization. It seems that my issue was due to some weird conflict in jQuery. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not comfortable with what you're doing with `{module_isloggedin}`, but if you say it has a value of either 0 or 1 (integers) and you're wrapping it inside quotes like this:

```
var loggedin = '{module_isloggedin}';
```

... when you compare it like this:

```
  if  (loggedin == 1){
```

... it will always evaluate to true (because `string` == 1)

Try either taking the quotes away around your module or add them around the `1` in your comparison.

Comment: I can't really explain why it is in quotes to be honest. It is a javascript example from a site that uses the same functionality and works. The module in the quotes will return the integer 1 and not the string "1". My main issue is the fact that the div is not hiding in the first place, which it should be without worrying about the module value.

Comment: When looking at the source code of the page, the {module_isloggedin} will show a value of 0 in place where the {module_isloggedin} tag should be.

Comment: It looks like the code you grabbed is supposed to be preprocessed by a templating library, which would populate it with the proper value at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var loggedin = !!parseInt('{module_isloggedin}');
```